Menu Issue in NobleUI Theme
I need your help again because I can't find the error.
I purchased the NobleUI theme because I wanted to get things done quickly. Now I have the problem that when I click on a menu link, a different menu category automatically opens, and the 'active' status is set on the first, second, or third menu link.
I have uploaded two images to better illustrate the problem visually:
<li class="nav-item nav-category">Kundenverwaltung</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#kunden" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="kunden">
    <i class="link-icon" data-feather="mail"></i>
    <span class="link-title">Menü 1</span>
    <i class="link-arrow" data-feather="chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="kunden">
    <ul class="nav sub-menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.kunde.all')}}" class="nav-link">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.kunde.create')}}" class="nav-link">2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.kunde.kategorie')}}" class="nav-link">3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#partner" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="partner">
    <i class="link-icon" data-feather="mail"></i>
    <span class="link-title">Menu 2</span>
    <i class="link-arrow" data-feather="chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="partner">
    <ul class="nav sub-menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.partner.all')}}" class="nav-link">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.partner.create')}}" class="nav-link">2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{route('admin.partner.kategorie')}}" class="nav-link">3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>

If anyone has experience with the NobleUI theme or similar menu issues, I would be very grateful for your support. Tips for troubleshooting or suggestions from developers familiar with Bootstrap and the NobleUI theme would be especially helpful.
Thank you in advance for your support!


I tried to solve the issue using ChatGPT, but after three hours, I still haven't had any success.
Action: Click on the menu item "Menu 1 -> 1". Observation: After the click, both "Menu 1 -> 1" and "Menu 2 -> 1" are selected and highlighted simultaneously. Expectation: Only "Menu 1 -> 1" should be selected and activated. Issue: Regardless of the menu item clicked, the corresponding item in the next menu in the sequence is also selected.

Can you specify 1. Where did you click exactly 2. What did you expect exactly and 3. What happened exactly?

@LajosArpad
Action: Click on the menu item "Menu 1 -> 1".
Observation: After the click, both "Menu 1 -> 1" and "Menu 2 -> 1" are selected and highlighted simultaneously.
Expectation: Only "Menu 1 -> 1" should be selected and activated.
Issue: Regardless of the menu item clicked, the corresponding item in the next menu in the sequence is also selected.
